# Extracting digits from a regular expression

Tags: javascript

```
var myString = 'Sent from your Zoom trial account - Your verification code is: 621226';
var regEx = /(\d+)$/g;
var result = regEx.exec(myString);
```

However result = [621226, 621226] instead of just [621226]

http://plnkr.co/edit/8ZbFHDAk0iLwEjpfkQaq?p=info

Comment: Question uses `.exec()`, though plnkr uses `.match()` with `.exec()` pattern? `String.prototype.match()` should be chained to input string

Comment: `var result = regEx.exec(myString)[1];`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `.match()` with `regEx` as parameter chained to `myString`.

```js
var myString = 'Sent from your Zoom trial account - Your verification code is: 621226';
var regEx = /(\d+)$/g;
var result = myString.match(regEx);
console.log(result);
```

plnkr http://plnkr.co/edit/cdwFsPKq9X3tCnub6FzL?p=preview